# AngularJS Php file with angular in it not working after $http

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a php file with a bunch of angular stuff in it and it works fine when I include it directly, however once I include that php file via $http like this:

```
$http.get('include/step'+step+'.php').
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $("#tab_"+step).html(data);
});
```

It stops working, then I can see stuff like: {{category.title}} etc being shows as text rather than it fetching its value.

I'm starting out with angular and I'm trying to just make angular recognise the code that gets added via an ajax response or just a $http response.

I also tried doing

but I got this angular.bootstrap(data);

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'eventCatCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

eventCatCtrl was the first of my controllers in that file that was generated via $http.

I also did this angular.bootstrap(data, ['eventApp']); eventApp was the name of my main module.
Just for info all this http stuff is being done inside a div and I've defined my module on body, if it matters.

**On the request of more code:**

Function is triggered from this:

```
<div class="form-group progress-tracker__buttons" ng-controller="StepChange">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-save" value="Save">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-next disabled" value="Next" ng-click="changeStep($event)">
    <div class="last-saved">Last saved: Not saved yet</div>
</div>
```

Here's my module, controller and function:

```
var eventApp = angular.module('eventApp', []);

eventApp.controller('StepChange', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.changeStep = function($event){
        $http.get('include/step2.php').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $("#tab_2").html(data);
        });
    };
});
```

In my step2.php file I have this portion:

```
<div class="panel-group form-group sortable" id="catAccordion" ng-controller="eventCatCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="category in categories.list">
        <p>{{category.title}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a factory as such:

```
eventApp.factory('EventCategories', function () {
    var EventCategories = {};
    EventCategories.list = [
        {
            name: "Robert Downey Jr.",
            character: "Tony Stark / Iron Man"
        },
        {
            name: "Chris Evans",
            character: "Steve Rogers / Captain America"
        }
    ];
    return EventCategories;
});
```

And I have a controller like this for that factory:

```
eventApp.controller("eventCatCtrl", function($scope, EventCategories){
    $scope.categories = EventCategories;
});
```

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: @cbass Please have a look and let me know if you require anything else.

Comment: you need to `$http.get()` an actual web endpoint, rather than an include. angular cant process php files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize controller after angular has been bootstrapped. Because of this, you are receiving the error

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'eventCatCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Also, `$http.get` should be used for saving/fetching data. For including other layouts and UI's, you should use templates and directives. You'll be able to control display of embedded html content using variables in `$scope`.

### **Lazy loading in Angular**

http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/

Also, you'll have to expose controller register service, like this:

```
eventApp.config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {

    eventApp.controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
}]);
```

And, where you are registering the controller, use the following:

```
eventApp.controllerProvider("eventCatCtrl", function($scope, EventCategories){
    $scope.categories = EventCategories;
 });
```

Comment: I see. 

I was previously using ajax to get the files and then thought of implementing angular instead of the other stuff, I'll give templates a try. However is there a way to make a file work by calling it via $http, now that I know it's not the most ideal case I'll probably refrain myself from using it but is there a way to make it work?

Comment: There is a way of loading files using AJAX, for that you'll have to go through routes, have to setup a way of invoking controller after bootstrapping. If you are interested, i'll post some articles on same...

Comment: Can you let me know about that, I was loading files with AJAX before but angular wasn't recognising them and was presenting me with the same result as I have right now.

Comment: Thanks Rohit I'll check that stuff out.

Comment: Should I use ng-include, ng-if + ng-show or ajax lazy loading? What is the best way in terms of performance, I just want to add a template inside a div once I click a button.

Comment: All 3 of them have their advantages and disadvantages, if ur template is small, i'll recommend nf-if ng-show and if ur template is big and includes lot of js, i'll recommend lazy loading...

Comment: Thanks Rohit for all that help, my reputation is low so can't vote up but this answer cleared my issue for me so I'll accept it.